# I have upgraded my old project with PHP-7 and CodeIgniter-3, now everything is working fine, only DOMPDF generating errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I have upgraded my old project with PHP-7 and CodeIgniter-3, now everything is working fine, only DOMPDF generating errors, which was working fine with php 5.4 and oudated CI version

Error as follow:

```
..
Severity: 8192

Message: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead

Filename: include/autoload.inc.php
..
```

I have attached screenshot of it..

Please answer me..[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "error" is actually a run-time warning from the new version of PHP letting you know you should upgrade something. That "something" is DOMPDF.

The version of DOMPDF you have now is using an old PHP function, `__autoload()`, that should be replaced with `spl_autoload_register()`. The current version of DOMPDF has been updated to use `spl_autoload_register()`. The answer to your problem is to upgrade to the latest version of DOMPDF.

Comment: I searched a lot but I didn't get the latest dompdf which will resolve that error. If you know please comment the link.

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) has instructions for installation via Download, GIT, or  Composer.

Comment: I merged above updated dompdf, though same issue. Basic including files also not present in relevant zip file

Comment: If files previously included are not provided it could be because, 1) those file are not needed in the newer version, or 2) they are custom code developed to integrate dompdf with CodeIgniter. Both of the above might be true.

Comment: @DFriend. very helpful for me. I already upvote the answer. Thank you